# Retrieving URL using RCurl gives different date format than in browser

Tags: r, curl

I am attempting to scrape a mobile-formatted webpage using RCurl, at the following URL:

http://m.fire.tas.gov.au/?pageId=incidentDetails&closed_incident_no=161685

Using this code:

```
library(RCurl)
options( RCurlOptions = list(verbose = TRUE, useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13"))
inurl <- getURL(http://m.fire.tas.gov.au/?pageId=incidentDetails&closed_incident_no=161685)
```

Note that I have attempted to set the user-agent to look like a Chrome browser - the results I get are the same with or without doing this.  When I view the URL in Chrome, the dates come out formatted like this, with a time stamp as well:

[image: Screenshot of text on web page]

And the HTML source matches that:

```
Last Updated: 24-Aug-2009 11:36<br>
First Reported: 24-Aug-2009 11:24<br>
```

But within R, after I've retrieved the data from the URL, the dates are formatted like this:

```
Last Updated: 2009-08-24<br>    
First Reported: 2009-08-24<br>
```

Any ideas what's going on here? I figure the server is responding to the browser/Curl's user-agent or region or language or something similar, and returning different data, but can't figure out what I need to set in RCurl's options to change this.

Comment: The only think I can recommend is to figure out which headers chrome is sending (by inspecting the network tag in the debug tools) and then systematically replicate until you get the same results in R and the browser.

Comment: Referer is a fairly common header for sites to check, but I tried setting and it didn't help.

Comment: @hadley i might've made a beginner's mistake, but i tried using all the request headers shown under the inspect element > network box.  even when all add_headers() match chrome, it doesn't work.  :/  it's a weird site.. if you change the value of closed_incident_no it jumps btw the two formats

Comment: @AnthonyDamico and now it's returning it for me every time.  I suspect weirdness with that server

Comment: Okay I'll just put this down to general weirdness on the site I'm trying to scrape then.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the server is expecting 'Accept-Language' header:

```
library(RCurl)
getURL("http://m.fire.tas.gov.au/?pageId=incidentDetails&closed_incident_no=161685", 
       httpheader = c("Accept-Language" = "en-US,en;q=0.5"))
```

works for me (returns `First Reported: 24-Aug-2009 11:24<br>` etc.). I discovered this by using [HttpFox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/httpfox/) Firefox plugin.